# Is it possible that $A \neq B$ and $AT^{-1}(A)=BT^{-1}(B)$, where $T(\cdot)$ is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $T:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a linear map. Suppose that $$AT^{-1}(A)=BT^{-1}(B)\,,$$
where $T^{-1}(A)$ is the matrix inverse of $T(A).$ Is it possible that $A\neq B$?

Comment: Saying that $T^{-1}(A)$ is the "matrix inverse" of $T (A)$ seems strange given that $T$ is a linear map on $n\times n $ matrices.  It would not be defined often because $T (A) $ will happen to be singular.   If it is what you mean,  a better notation is $(T (A))^{-1}$, to avoid confusion with the  inverse of $T$ as a linear map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by linearity $B=-A$ also works.

Comment: There will generally be more for a specific $T$. For $T=I$, any solution to $A^2=B^2$ will work, for example. If $T$ is block-diagonal, you can probably transform in each block's region. It's not obvious what happens if $T$ is diagonalisable; it may or may not be possible to act on each transform each eigenspace separately.

Answer (score 1):

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be defined by $T(A)=A^t$. Then $T^2=id$, hence $T^{-1}=T$.

Thus $AT^{-1}(A)=BT^{-1}(B)$ means $AA^t=BB^t$.

It is your turn to find an example that $AA^t=BB^t$ does not imply $A=B$